# command -v <foo> returns wrong result after overwriting <foo> as function

Tags: bash, command, git, dot-files, which

I have the following functions in my `.bashrc` which just creates a python project with `venv` and creates gitignore and readme, after I initialise with git as: `git init python`

````
__git_init_folder_for_python(){
local README='
### Description
Python3 Project

### Installation```
python3 -m venv ./
source bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```'

local GITIGNORE='
### For venv
__pycache__/
bin/
lib/
include/
pyenv.cfg
'
## $(command -v git) fails
$(which git) init \ 
  && python3 -m venv ./ \
  && . bin/activate \
  && pip3 freeze > requirements.txt 
  [[ ! -f "README.md" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$README" > README.md
  [[ ! -f ".gitignore" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$GITIGNORE" > .gitignore
}

__make_git_folder(){
  case "$1" in
    python )
      __git_init_folder_for_python
      ;;
    * )
      echo "not found"
  esac
}

git(){
  local ARG1="$1"
  local ARG2="$2"
  case "$ARG1" in
    'init' )
      if [[ "$ARG2" == "python" ]]; then
        __make_git_folder "$ARG2"
      else
        $(which -a git | head -1) "$ARG1" # $(command -v git) fails
      fi
      ;;
    *)
      $(which -a git | head -1) "$@" # $(command -v git) fails
  esac
}
````

I think I know why it is happening because I have overwritten `git` as bash function. so:

```
$ command -v git
git
```

as:

```
$ type git | head -1
git is a function
```

But, if I use `which` instead, even after overwriting `git` as function, it returns the correct path.

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

How can I make `command -v` return the correct path without explicitly declaring the path before the git function? Is it a bad practice to overwrite functions like this? If so, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make command -v return the correct path

You can't. If you want the full path use `which`. However, I don't think you need this full path. Just call

```
command git ...
```

without the `-v` flag. The flag doesn't have an intuitive behavior and it doesn't print what `command` without the flag would do.

> But, if I use which instead, even after overwriting git as function, it returns the correct path.

`which` is an external program. It does not know of bash functions. `command` is a builtin.